# Floating/Always above dialog

Tags: c++, winapi, qt, dialog, x11

I've noticed in GIMP that when a dialog is opened it does not disable the parent window. The parent window can still be used, while the child window floats in front of it.
I want to do the same thing, how ever for me when I click on my parent window it pushes the children to the back, such that the parent comes to the front.

I'm using Qt QDialog's but happy to do platform specific code to get this working.

I've been looking here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx

but nothing seems to do what I'm after. I have a dodgey solution currently where I set the window to `HWND_TOPMOST` when my app receives focus, then disable this when it looses focus, but its not ideal as message boxes are being pushed behind these top most windows.
ie.

```
SetWindowPos(winId(), stayOnTop ? HWND_TOPMOST : HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I didnt have parenting setup correctly on my dialog! It needed to be parented to the parent dialog/main window and then it just works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`setWindowFlags()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) including the [`Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#WindowType-enum) flag.

Comment: But that keeps it on top of all windows. I just want to keep it on top of its parent. As is discussed here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15464-WindowStaysOnTopHint

Comment: Yes I misunderstood you. I just assumed that your parenting was right because once that is so then as you say, there is nothing else to do.